# How to create phone dialer effect in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, core-animation

I want to create phone dialer effect, so how can i make that effect?. Is any API are available for that? I have set the images are in the image view, the images are in the circle shape. Now i want to touch and drag the images, If i drag the single images , it would move all the images to the certain path. Please see my screen shot.

[image]

Please help me out.

Thanks!

Comment: a rotary phone-dialer api? People expect way too much these days. ---- Look at the real phone. They don't move the holes along a path. They turn a disc with holes in it. I would try to put all images into one view and rotate that view.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a view (View A) and set the background color to transparent.
2. Add the images views as subview to View A
3. Override the following method in View A:

   ```
   - (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

   // Only return YES if the touch is in one of the subviews 
   //   - we dont care about touches that are just in this view

   for (UIView* view in self.subviews) {

       // We need to convert the point into the recievers co-ordinate system
       // (as per the documentation on 'pointInside:withEvent')

       CGPoint convertedPoint = [self convertPoint:point toView:view];

       if ([view pointInside:convertedPoint withEvent:event]) {
           return YES;
       }
   }
   return NO;
   }
   ```
4. Respond to touches moved to change the center point of view A.  If you need to rotate about a point you will have to use some trig/maths.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a UIPanGestureRecognizer to detect panning/dragging on your parent image view. Then just apply a CGAffineTransform to rotate that view based on the user's finger position.

```
// Calculate the rotation you want
CGFloat radians = degreesToRadians(position*totalRotation);
[dialerView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(radians)];
```

You would need to figure out how to calculate the position and totalRotation.